# mod_rewrite is not working for me

Tags: database, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to set up mod_rewrite for a website using apache

here is my sentence :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/Actualites/([^/]+)/?$ news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1 [L]
```

but it's not working

I have other rewrite working, I tested something simple like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ancienne-url\.html$ /nouvelle-url.html [R=301,L]
```

and this is working.

I tried to put it in the Htaccess and in the Vhost, both don't work.

I would also like to get the following

`news/Actualites/MYPRODUCT` when I have the url like `news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=MYNUMERIC_ID`

I don't know if it is possible to have "words" on one side, when it is normali the numerical ID of the side…
Thanks in advance
Lawrence

Comment: Are you declaring your RewriteBase? If you are on a VPS you often need this to get stuff working.

Comment: I'm not on a VPS, but I don't know about RewriteBase… What should I setup?

Comment: Is your server configured to allow override?

Comment: unfortunatly not…
I have added RewriteBase /

Comment: Lawrence I'm not skilled in mod_rewrite to answer on this topic, but when stuck on some code, I like (same as you seem to try) to start with as simple "plain-vanilla" as possible, and when I get that working, then work up from there... adding the details I actually need, one by one, to discover where the problem lays.  You did try the simple `RewriteRule ^ancienne-url\.html$ /nouvelle-url.html [R=301,L]`, so now maybe try something in between that and where you want to go, this?: `RewriteRule ^news/Actualites/(test)$ news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1 [L]`.  If that fails, break it down further.

Comment: keep updating your question here with the new things you try that may shed more light on what is going on.

Comment: Is there any conflicting .htaccess file in 'news/Actualites/', or in any of the parent/child directories that would factor in?  (Again, let me say, I am mostly mod_rewrite newbie.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/Actualites/([^/]+)/?$ news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

For the first part of the question.

For the 2nd part you could achieve it with a RewriteRule but that would mean hard-coding all your URLs, which wouldn't be a very good idea.

```
RewriteRule ^news/Actualites/MYPRODUCT$ news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=MYNUMERIC_ID [NC,QSA,L]
```

And then you'd need to replicate the above line replacing MYPRODUCT and MYPRODUCT_ID for each different URL.

What you would normally do in this situation is have a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^news/Actualites/([^/]+)$ news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

And the the actualites_d.tpl script would query a database or whatever to get the information required for the passed in URL value:

```
SELECT * FROM tbdProduct WHERE fldProductURLSlug = SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of problems with your rewrite rules, as a general practice it's generally better to add in the full URL to prevent cyclic local rewrites.  The second issue is your rewrite rule is expecting the URL to start with news... but in reality it's /news so to fix compatibility it should look more or less something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/Actualites/(.*)/.*$ http://{$HTTP_HOST}/news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1 [R=301,L]
```

SO in this example you'll see that I added the / and a ? at the start of the rewrite rule, that is for compatibility in case the / isn't set.  Secondly you'll see the (.*)  The round brackets indicate a variable assignment, You can set multiple of those and then use them with $1 $2 and so forth.  Finally I set the redirect location as a 301 redirect.  Using RewriteBase is irrelevant unless you are serving under an aliased directory for instance like /blog/

The previous example sets RewriteBase to / and then does the rewrite rule for ^news.  But that does not take into account some requests that you may receive that excludes the starting slash.

Another example for completeness sake would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/Actualites/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/.*$ http://{$HTTP_HOST}/news/Actualites_d.tpl?SKU=$1&orderid=$2&somvar=$3 [R=301,L]
```